# JavaScript defering

Tags: javascript, deferred, head

Is placing `<script>` tags in just before closing the `<body>` tag the same sa placing them in the `<head>` section and specifying a `defer="defer"` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes/No.

Yes because placing the defer tag waits until the document is loaded before executing.

No because placing the `<script>` before the `</body>` tag doesn't necessarily mean the document is completely loaded as you can have other tags between the closing body tag and the closing HTML tag.  Example

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>...</script>
  </body>
  <link/>
  <script>
  although it is invalid HTML most browsers will render tags outside the body. This is 
  probably more of an error in code
  <div> some content</div>
</html>
```

Also of note, the defer attribute of the script tag is not functional in all browsers.

**Edited:**

In regards to performance for faster loading pages you may want to look at this article it provides some guidelines including where to put script and css

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: I ask in terms of speed, not to be able to use the DOM in JavaScript for which I would use events. JavaScript that's placed before body is not needed for page structure or such and can thus be loaded last, after the page is viewable. I don't understand what you mean in the "no" part. "placing the before the tag doesn't necessarily mean the document is completely loaded as you can have other tabs between the closing body tag and the closing HTML tag" Why would I have tags betwwen </body> and </html>?

Comment: @Francisc I have edited my answer as I had a few formatting issues. Sorry about that.  In regards to your comment for speed.  The only Item I would like to mention is that the browser will cache the JS files as needed and you will not actually load a js file in cache.  Using the defer does not necessarily benefit you because the defer will only halt execution until the the page is fully loaded. It does not defer the call to obtain the script file itself.  Therefore in your instance you will want to place script tags after the `<\body>` tag for better performance.

Comment: @JohnHartsock no comment about poor cross-browser support?

Comment: @Raynos I did mention that the defer attribute is "not functional in all browsers"

Comment: @JohnHartsock did I mention I'm blind? Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

> defer Requires Gecko 1.9.1 This
>   Boolean attribute is set to indicate
>   to a browser that the script is meant
>   to be executed after the document has
>   been parsed. Since this feature hasn't
>   yet been implemented by all other
>   major browsers, authors should not
>   assume that the script’s execution
>   will actually be deferred. Never call
>   document.write() from a defer script
>   (since Gecko 1.9.2, this will blow
>   away the document). The defer
>   attribute shouldn't be used on scripts
>   that don't have the src attribute.
>   Since Gecko 1.9.2, the defer attribute
>   is ignored on scripts that don't have
>   the src attribute. However, in Gecko
>   1.9.1 even inline scripts are deferred if the defer attribute is set.

When the document has finished parsing and at the end of the `<body>` tag are similar but not the exact same.

It's also important to note this only works for scripts with an external `src` set.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, but the browsers do not guarantee they will execute JavaScript after loading the page unless you specify so (defer="defer").

Comment: I don't understand, isn't that what I said: that they will execute code with defer="defer" after loading the DOM?

Comment: Your question was: are X and Y the same things? Well, in fact, in most cases they will be the same thing. What I said is that this is not ensured. That is, the browsers do not tell you: "If you put your script at the end, it will be executed after loading". They generally do that, but if they run your script before rendering the page, they will not be going against their documentations, as these later do not say anything about that.